# Ajax pass form ID values into url to send one submit .get("url")

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url, submit

```
<form id="adultval" class="">
    <input id="txtFirstName" type="text" name="First Name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" minlength="2" required>

    <input id="txtLastName" type="text" name="Last Name" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" minlength="2" required>

    <input class="btnSubmit" type="submit" id="btnAdult" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

$.get("https://somewhere.com/_services?uid=BS1345&firstname="+$('#txtFirstName')+"&lastname="+$('#txtLastName')+"&email=;
```

On submit I'm having trouble correctly capturing form values and putting them in the URL string.

Comment: Never name an input `submit`, it overwrites the native `form.submit` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correctly use next code, [jquery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

```
$.get('https://somewhere.com/_services', {
  uid:'BS1345',
  firstname: $('#txtFirstName').val(),
  lastname: $('#txtLastName').val(),
  email: '',
});
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried this method before and it's returning nothing so I though I had something wrong in the .get .val() method. If i use static values it submits correctly, it's just not grabbing the form value? I'm getting [object Object] returned.

Comment: or nothing at all

Answer (score 0):

I think your code try to get form control value with jQuery selector like `$('#txtFirstName')`. Use `val` method to get form control value.

```
$('#txtFirstName').val()
```

http://api.jquery.com/val/